# tkinker inserting a csv into treeview

Tags: tkinter, treeview

```
def read_csv_file(csv='########'):
    # Read the CSV file and create a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=False)

    # Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Insert the current row into the Treeview widget
        self.tree.insert("", "end", values=row)
```

[image]

Hi all, I am using a python function to import a csv via button in tkinter app. but the rows are not reading correctly from the csv format. It should be reading row wise like this for the top row. Is there something going wrong with the tree.insert I am using?

[image]

Comment: It is better to post the content of the CSV file for reference.

Comment: Hey, it is a csv with the same columns as the tkinter file

Comment: You need to convert `row` to `list` of values using `row.to_list()`.  So try `tree.insert("", "end", values=row.to_list())`.